# Find the minimum possible value for the area of a rectangle which is divided into 9 smaller rectangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Rectangle with sides $(x+y+z)$ and $(a+b+c)$ is divided into 9 smaller rectangles. Find the minimum possible area of the rectangle.

The areas of 4 of the smaller rectangles are:
$$ax=8, \quad ay=10, \quad by=5, \quad cz=12$$

So, $$P=35+az+bx+bz+cx+cy$$
I got: $$a=2b, y=\frac54x \implies P=39+ \frac32az +\frac94cx$$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: You also know for example that $x=\dfrac{8}{a}$ and $z= \dfrac{12}{c}$ so giving you an expression in two variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by writing $z=12/c$. You get

$$P = 39 + 18\frac ac + \frac94cx$$

Now put $x=8/a$

$$P = 39 + 18\frac ac + 18\frac ca$$

Put $a/c=t$

$$P=39+18t + \frac{18}{t}$$

You can quickly see that we need to minimise the last two terms. You can see by inspection or differentiation that it is minimum at $t=1$ and $t=-1$. Since ratio of two positive quantities cannot be negative, we take $t=a/c=1$.

So,

$$P=39+18\cdot1 +\frac{18}{1} = 39+18+18=75$$